# remove duplicate values given it is false or true

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

So if I have a table:

```
col1  |  col2
 x    |   f
 x    |   t
 y    |   t 
 z    |   t 
 q    |   f
 q    |   t
```

For all the duplicate values I want to keep the false value. So,

```
col1  |  col2
 x    |   f
 y    |   t 
 z    |   t 
 q    |   f
```

How do I do this in Postgres? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible in your schema that there are `col1` duplicates but none of them have `col2 = false` (e.g there are rows (x, t), (x, t) but (x, f) doesn't exist)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is assuming a whole lot about your table, but based on your example I think this would work:

```
delete from my_table t1
where
  col2 and
  exists (
    select null
    from my_table t2
    where t1.col1 = t2.col1
    group by t2.col1
    having count (*) > 1
)
```

I'm assuming your t/f is a boolean datatype, not a character.  If that's a bad assumption, you could change `not col2` to `col2 = 't'`.

Some warnings:

- If you have multiple duplicates, this will delete all false values, not just the first
- If you have multiple duplicates, this will leave all true values, not just one
- If you want to be more selective about which false value(s) you delete or which true value(s) you keep, it's probably possible, but that depends on your content

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it using a [WITH clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) checking for falses in the table, and do an in-line query against that checking for trues:

```
WITH false_vals AS
  (SELECT col1, col2
   FROM example_schema.table_with_dupes
   WHERE col2='f')

DELETE
FROM example_schema.table_with_dupes
WHERE col2 = 't'
  AND col1 IN
    (SELECT col1
     FROM false_vals)
```

To check what you're going to delete before executing this, you can replace the `DELETE` line with `SELECT *`.